# TypeScript - why compiler allows undefined class attributes with explicit type specified?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

Why code below compiles?

```
class Foo {
  public readonly foo: string;
}

const f = new Foo();
console.log(f.foo);  // undefined
```

Even with all these `--strictNullChecks` and `--noImplicit*` it compiles and output `undefined`.

Comment: ... and the answer is here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the typescript issues, I have found that you have to use `--strict` mode to see compile error on your code.

[Github Issue topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476)(Please search for below text)

> mhegazy commented on Apr 22
>   Reopening this issue. New plan, look into adding the check under a new
>   flag (on by default under `--strict`).

Comment: This is the *plan* but it isn't implemented yet, nor has it been [scheduled](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476#issuecomment-335293240).